# Matlab2016 splitapply with a function that has a nonscalar output

Tags: matlab, split-apply-combine

I have a table in Matlab2016 and I'd like to apply a function on groupings of a column. I know the splitapply function can do this but I'd like to use a function such as tiedrank where the output is nonscalar but still specific to the entries in the column it is applied to.
For example, I want to calculate the **y** column using the tiedrank function on the elements in the **x** column. The tiedrank should be based on the groups [0,1] under **t**. So ranking the elements with **t** value 0 and **t** value 1 seperately. Preferably using a function that can be applied once for the whole table. Is there any way to do this with the splitapply function or any other function? Thanks!

```
t x y  
0 3 1  
1 8 1  
0 5 3  
0 4 2  
1 9 2
```

Comment: Can you provide some example input and expected output?

Comment: Can you break this up into multiple sentences?

Comment: @Suever I've added an example that I hope clarifies things. My main issue is with using tiedrank on tables. It seemed to work well with cell arrays however I couldn't use a variable grouping function for the whole cell array

Comment: @I.S So that looks like the input. What is the output you expect?

Comment: @Suever the y column is the output I expect- the ranking of x based on the variable groupings in t